# How to connect two VMs with different IP ranges to access each other?

Tags: networking, kvm, bridge

Using KVM I have created four VMs, I have two public Ip addresses for my VMs, I know that I can assign these IPs to two of the VMs and connect them to internet by bridging my host's physical interface to these two VMs.
 Now I want to assign two local IP addresses to other two VMs such that all my four VMs can access each other. 
Is it possible at all? if yes how can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope this is your environment.

```
Host 1 - 1 Bridged NIC Network 

Host 2 - 1 Bridged NIC Network 

Host 3 - Local NIC Network

Host 4 - Local NIC Network
```

If you add 1 more NIC to Host 1 and Host 2 respectively and then assign local IP to them as in Host 3 and Host 4. All your 4 Host can communicate with each other.

The Resulting environment will be like

```
Host 1 - 1 Bridged NIC Network, 1 Local NIC Network

Host 2 - 1 Bridged NIC Network, 1 Local NIC Network

Host 3 - 1 Local NIC Network

Host 4 - 1 Local NIC Network
```

Comment: thanks, I used Qemu's default NAT for my local networks.

Comment: Yeah, that will work.